# How to execute Print statement after getting input from user

Tags: java

I have code which is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class shoham
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your name is: ");
        System.out.print(name.nextLine());
    }
}
```

When I execute this command, I get output like:

```
Enter your name:
Your name is: 
*****                               (user input)
*****                                (output)
```

Can anyone give a code that gives output like:

```
Enter your name: **** - (user input)
Your name is: **** - (output from user input)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're reading input after your print statements. You probably want:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // do this first, and give it a 
                                      // better name

System.out.print("Enter your name: ");  // use print to keep it on one line
String name = in.nextLine();  // read input, store it
System.out.print("Your name is: ");
System.out.println(name);  // print name
```

```
Enter your name: Joe
Your name is: Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this ie try using `print` only instead of `println`:-

```
Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String name = name.nextLine();
System.out.print("Your name is: ");
System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scanner.nextLine()
    System.out.println("Your name is: "+name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your code:

```
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your name is: "+name.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got lot of sloutions here, but you need to know the issue with your code is,

You **did not store** the `input from the user`.

```
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");  
String name = name.nextLine();  // read input, store it
```